# Man goes back in time to observe WW2 and gets stranded in an alternate future

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, paradox

Anyone know the name of this science fiction short story. Man goes back in time to observe Second World War, falls in love, tries to return to future but ends up in a alternate future with no power source and cannot return to the past. Something about the 'Probable Con'. Driving me nuts trying to find.  Someone borrowed this sci-fi collection years ago and lost it.

Comment: Do you remember when you bought it?

Answer (score 14):

[Alfred Bester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Bester), ["The Probable Man"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46423). First published in Astounding, July 1941. (yes, even before USA entered the WW2). It can be found recently in his collection Redemolished.

The description fits perfectly.

Comment: FYI -- This story can be read in its entirety courtesy of archive.org at: https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v27n05_1941-07_dtsg0318-LennyS/page/n73